# VBA/Access: Track the last date a macro was run via a command button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using command buttons to import excel files into various tables, and I want to track the last time each table was updated (i.e. the last time the command button was clicked and ran successfully).

I've tried doing this by adding a text field next to each command button, and then adding `Me.TextField1.Value = Date` to the `_Click` subroutine for each button. This fills in the date correctly, but it doesn't save the value when I close the data base.

How do I keep the date value from resetting every time I reopen the database?

Comment: Can you modify the tables? Could you just save that timestamp in the tables as another attribute?

Comment: Store the value in a table within the database.

Comment: Add a column to your database like `LastSaved` and save the date to that registry. Also you can create a `LastSaved` Table that stores the TableName and LastSaved date.

Comment: The reason the date in your text field is not saved is probably because it is not 'bound' to a field in your database - and you have no code in place to save it. My personal preference would be to create a new table to hold a one-line summary of some activity you performed (like an import). I would not add it to the data you import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would probably approach this is to **add a table** to your database that contains a **list of all the Excel files** you import on a routine basis. You would store the filename of the Excel file in one column, and the **updated date** in another column.

[image]

Then you can use the `DLookup()` function to pull the updated date into your text box by your command button.

Of course there are many approaches you could take here, but which one is best depends on your specific needs. If it is just you running this application on a single computer, you might find it easier to use the `SaveSetting`/`GetSetting` functions to save simple values to the registry.

```
SaveSetting "ExcelImporter", "sheet2.xlsx", "Updated", Now()
TextField1 = GetSetting("ExcelImporter", "sheet2.xlsx", "Updated")
```

If you have a lot of spreadsheets, you might consider a list box with two columns, one with the name of the file, and the other with the date it was last updated. Then you could use a single button to run the update, based on the selected file. Lots of options...  :-)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with `Dlookup`, and setting each default text field value as `Me.TextField.Value = DLookup("DateCreate", "MSysObjects", "Name='Table1'")`, and then also updating the value via the macro. This uses the Table Created date since the table is being deleted and recreated each time.

Comment: That's creative! Good idea to pull the date from `MSysObjects`. Just keep in mind that some objects like Forms and Reports can have their dates reset when you do a Compact/Repair.

Comment: Thanks, and I just tested with a Compact/Repair and it seems to be okay, thanks for bringing that up though!

Answer (score 1):

Add a Date/Time field to the table you are updating and set the `Default Value` property of the field to `Now()`. When new records are inserted, they will automatically have their insert date and time set.

If you are updating existing records, then update this field to `Now` explicitly.

You can query this date with

```
Dim lastUpdate As Variant
lastUpdate = DMax("DateFieldName", "TableName")
```

In addition, you see when each record has been inserted or updated.

---

`TextBox` values are not saved permanently, unless the `RecordSource` of the form has been set to a table or query and `ControlSource` of the `TextBox` has been set to a column of the table or query.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Custom Database Property to hold the last time the button was clicked.

```
Function getLastTimeClick() As Date
    Const PropertyName As String = "LastTimeClicked"
    On Error Resume Next
    getLastTimeClick = CurrentDb.Properties(PropertyName).Value
    If Err.Number = 3270 Then
        CurrentDb.Properties.Append CurrentDb.CreateProperty(PropertyName, dbDate, Now)
    End If
    CurrentDb.Properties(PropertyName).Value = Now
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```